# Get derivative method on base class variable

Tags: c#, class, derivative

I have two classes a base class `b` and the derivative. In my code I call a method with a base class parameter, but I want to detect if the parameter is the derivative. In the case it is the derivative, I want to call a method that is only in the derivative.

Example of my code:
Classes

```
public class Base {}

public class Derivative : Base {
    public void foo() {
        //do something...
    }
}
```

Method with parameter:

```
void Action (Base b) {
    if (b is Derivative) {
        b.foo();
    }
}
```

The problem is that it treats `b` as a `Base` class. Is it possible to keep this reference but use the derivative classes methods?

Comment: You can use [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/pattern-matching) `if(b is Derivative tmp) tmp.foo()`, but maybe you need to refactor `Action`, e.g. making it generic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In modern C#:

```
void Action (Base b) {
    if (b is Derivative derived) {
        derived.foo();
    }
}
```

In older C#:

```
void Action (Base b) {
    var derivative = b as Derivative;
    if(derivative != null) derivative.foo();    
}
```

I'd be wary of this pattern, but that's outside the scope of this question

Comment: Thanks for answering! You say I should be wary of using this pattern, why is that?

Comment: To explain it quickly, using inheritance, but then having code elsewhere you need to update everytime you make a new derived class, doesn't really make much sense. Check the Liskov sustitution principle (the L in "SOLID")

Comment: Thanks for the quick explanation and the references. This is very helpful, I would include it in your answer as a reference for future readers!

Comment: @Lae "pattern" and architectural answers are oppinionated (not everyone agrees on that), and are generally not welcome in Stack Overflow. I prefer to just answer the specific question (but maybe include a remark/comments, like this one is, with side notes)